# how to query posts using value in meta post array

Tags: post-meta

I googled this case for more than a week, I didn't get any correct answers

I have a post type called `listing`.

This listing have a rating stored in `wp_postmeta` table, the stored `meta_key` is `lp_listingpro_options` and the `meta_value` is an array like this

```
a:2:{s:6:"rating";s:1:"5";s:10:"listing_id";s:2:"27";}
a:2:{s:6:"rating";s:1:"4";s:10:"listing_id";s:2:"27";}
a:2:{s:6:"rating";s:1:"3";s:10:"listing_id";s:2:"27";}
```

the previous 3 values means that (where the listing id = 27 there is 3 ratings, `5,4,3`

What is the best way to do the following queries

1. Count number of ratings (I didn't find any ideas about how to start the query)
2. Top rated posts "most rated" (I didn't find any ideas about how to start the query)
3. Get rating that get `5` rating score

for solving the third item and getting listing that got `5` rating I did the following query

```
  $args =array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'meta_query' => array(
          array(
              'key'     => 'lp_listingpro_options',
              'value'   => array(
                  'key'     => 'rating',
                  'value'   => [5],
                  'compare' => '=',
              )
          ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Do you have multiple ratings stored using the same key for the same listing?

Comment: The fundamental issue is that you have a PHP data construct (serialized array), which you are trying to query with MySQL, which sees this as a string of random characters with no meaning.

Comment: @NightHawk the same key `lp_listingpro_options` used to store all ratings with the associated `listing_id`

Comment: Since the post ID (listing ID) is already stored with the post meta in the `post_id` field, you don't need that value in the serialized array. That leaves you with just the rating, which you can store as a single integer. If you can get it into that format, the three pieces of information are far easier to obtain.

Comment: There is listing => review => rating
The `post_id` is related to review associated with that listing
The second point I bought this theme from theme forest, I will edit it only